# How can I access the bodyHeight property of ag-grid with public variables/data?

Tags: typescript, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I have a project in ag-grid community react. It features a scrollable section that is populated with our data. We might have just one piece of data, we might have a million pieces of data. I'm also rendering a footer component for that grid, and its height must vary based on the bodyHeight property.

Presently, the only way I've found to do this is to access a private property, gridApi, on row nodes. This is not a pattern that I wish to use. Is there a better way of accessing the scrollable height of the ag-grid?

Answer (score 1):

You can't access the bodyHeight using public documented APIs, you'd have to access it via the Grid API internal methods/properties, which as you said is not an ideal solution for you.

The only other option would be to target the DOM element for the Viewport:

```js
const bodyViewport = document.querySelector('div[ref="eBodyViewport"]');
const clientHeight = bodyViewport.clientHeight;
const scrollHeight = bodyViewport.scrollHeight;
```

If you have one row of data, you'll probably have a lot of empty space inside the grid, you could use [Grid Auto Height](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/grid-size/#grid-auto-height) to tell the grid to auto-size it's height based on the data.

Comment: For better or for worse, auto height isn't an option. We have multiple tabs that a user can click to, with tab populating the grid with different information. The goal is to keep the grids sized consistently, regardless of how much data any individual grid does or does not have.

Comment: Another alternative would be to count the rows that are displayed by calling `api.getRenderedNodes()` or `api.getDisplayedRowCount()`, and use the row height of the rows to calculate an estimate for the viewport

Comment: That's a valid alternative. I think I'm going to utilize the suggestion you gave initially, though-- getting it from the document query selectors feels a little bit messy, but I think it's the most robust and precise solution.